# error: incompatible types: ImageActivity cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm getting this incompatible type error for my code. The error shows in ImageActivity class.

The error is in line: `imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageActivity.this, uploads);`
It says `ImageActivity.this` can't convert to Context type and I'm not sure why.

I did some research and I found that I could use `getActivity()` instead of `ImageActivity.this` I tried it but it didn't work either.

I attached the code files below, please help, thank you.

ImageActivity code:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListner {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference dataBaseRef;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private ValueEventListener DBListener;
    private List<Upload> uploads;
    private ProgressBar progressCircle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_activity);
        progressCircle.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_circle);
        recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        uploads = new ArrayList<>();
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageActivity.this, uploads);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imageAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImageActivity.this);
```

ImageAdapter code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private List<Upload> uploadList;
        private OnItemClickListner listner;
    
        public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploadList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.uploadList = uploadList;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, parent, false );
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = uploadList.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit().centerInside().into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploadList.size();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct `Context` class imported in `ImageAdapter`? Should be `import android.content.Context;`.

Comment: Did Mike's comment solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! it was the wrong import. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you don't need to use `getActivity()` or `ImageActivity.this`, if you want to get the context of your activity use `this`.

Comment: `ImageActivity.this` and `this` is same in OP's case because the code is in same class scope . And `getActivity()` is method of `Fragment` not `Activity`.